# CSS relative positioning, make all children relative to parent

Tags: html, css, position

Please consider the following HTML with styling.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;height: 600px;">
    <button id="create_new_estimate" style="position:relative;top:10px;left:10px;">
        Create New Estimate
    </button>

    <table style="position:relative;top:10px;left:300px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                cell 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                cell 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7meFL/1/).

I want to be able to position both of these elements side by side.  Eventually I will be adding many more elements inside this div.  I thought that `position:relative` would allow me to just give a `top` and `left` style attribute to each element to give it a position relative to the parent div.  However as you can see in this example, both elements have `top:10px;` so I would expect them to be next to each other, but they are not next to each other.

Do you know how what styling I can use, so I can simply give each element a `top` and `left` attribute to position them inside the parent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give you outter wrap div a "position:relative;" and change you current "position:relative;" to "position:absolute;"

Use "top" and "left" attributes alongside the "position:absolute" and think of "position:relative" as your anchor.  It you don't have a parent element with "position:relative" then the browser window becomes your anchor.

Comment: Yeah sounds like you want to use absolute positioning for your child elements.